# webmethod receiving null parameters on ios call

Tags: ios, macos, mono, appcelerator, webmethod

I'm developing an iOS app and it calls a Web service I wrote using mono and it runs using apache. However, when I call the webmethod, the parameters received are always null for example in this call (im using Appcelerator)

```
callparams = {
    username: String(username),
    password: String(password)
    };
    alert(String(username) + String(password));
    try {

        suds.invoke('Login', callparams, function(xmlDoc){
```

On the server, i have this webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Login(string username, string password)
    { 
        return username + "-00";
    }
```

When I run the simmulation, i only receive "-00" and not the username! why is this happening? I've also tried with integers and they're null too..

Nonetheless this works perfectly if i use the test form of the service..

Im running on MacOX 10.7.2 with mono 2.8.2 apache 2...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far I know you can not do this with mono services under fast-cgi-monoserver ou mod_mono. Use an alternative to asmx (our PageMethod) like [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/).